# Question about the local versus global non-dimensional number notation

Tags: fluid-dynamics, notation, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants, normalization

I apologize if this stackexchange is not the proper place to ask this question, if not please redirect me to the correct one.

I am writing a paper and where I am using a global [Rossby number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rossby_number) $Ro$ and a local Rossby number $Ro_L$. This is my notation for the local one at the moment. The $Ro$ refers to an average over the entire rotating wing, whereas the $Ro_L$ refers to a specific location along the span.

Is it proper notation for me to use $Ro_L$ for the local form, or should I adopt a different notation? I have seen literature use subscripts $x$ for the local position in other variables so I was thinking of using $Ro_r$ or $Ro_x$ since this seems to fit what others have used for other numbers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about notation, which is considered [off-topic/not constructive/primarily opinion-based,](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/).

Comment: The question has already been answered, and there is a notation tag so I don't understand why you'd consider it off-topic.

Comment: I suspect you didn't read the link I provided; please do. Note also that answers are pretty much irrelevant when it comes to the topicality of the *question*.

Comment: I read it after commenting. That's a very silly policy. If someone can learn something from the answer by reading this question in the future they should be afforded the opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you are consistent with your notation and define it at the beginning, it should be fine.

That said, you are writing a paper. So, what do the papers you cite use? Surely you're citing somebody who has defined a local Rossby number before, right? On the off chance that it is totally new, I would prefer either:

$\text{Ro}_l$ where $l$ means "local" (also note -- I feel non-dimensional numbers should not be in italics like other variables). This is because often $L$ means some reference length in a problem, and that's what I would assume it meant just by looking at the symbol.

But, I would prefer to see: $\text{Ro}_x$ where $x$ could be $y$ or $z$ depending on how your field usually denotes a coordinate in the "span" direction. This is how I am used to seeing boundary layer Reynolds numbers based on distance from the leading edge for example, and there is little ambiguity with other potential meanings since $x$ is almost always a coordinate and not a reference something or a word meaning something else.

That said, check what you cite and see what they use. That is always the best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have not read a paper where they focus much on the $Ro_l$ but I will check google scholar. The journal I am writing for requires non-dimensional numbers to be in italics though so I have no say regarding that. I have already used $x$, $y$, and $z$ when defining my mesh so I can't use that, but my local span distance is $r$. Should I use $Ro_r$ if I can't anything?

Comment: I know it's been a while since I posted this, but a paper by Thierry Jardin in 2014 on the LEV uses Ro(r). I haven't found any other usages so I followed suit in my paper.